# Build a pipeline in AzureDevOps for Sql Server on prem to run sql scripts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to build a pipe line in Azure DevOps to run sql scripts on premises, I know this it works because I've done it in the past (3 years ago but don't remember what task I've used).
Please can someone help me with the right steps (which task/components) to use in worder to build it.
Not looking to build a pipe line to deploy DACPAC files.

The best will be to come up with all the steps like: Create Artifact,
Create pipeline (all steps and task),
Create release (all steps and task).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with any of the ways below:

1. Use a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to execute the [**Invoke-Sqlcmd**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet like as below.

   ```
   Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "{scriptfilepath}" -ServerInstance {SqlServer} -Database {DbName} -Username "{userName}" -Password "{Password}" -QueryTimeout 36000 -Verbose
   ```
2. On the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=SQL%20script&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance) of Azure DevOps, you can find some pipeline task extensions that can be used to run SQL scripts. You can install one of them into your Azure DevOps organization/collection for use.

   - [Execute SQL Script](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.ExecuteSqlScript)
   - [Run SQL / SQLCMD Scripts passing multiple SQLCMD variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=SQL%20script&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance)

Comment: Thank you Bright Ran, I found all these information, but still unable to built the pipe line. At the moment I've downloaded one of the task from/component from Marketplace. I will test it on my local machine before I will implement at work. Hope for that to work. I was looking for some information where it provides me with all the steps.